# Not reaching the API after deploying to render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, deployment, render

I'm trying to deploy my website on Render.

Locally my code works just fine yet I cannot seem to make it work after deploying it.

I'm getting this error in developer tools on the website

```
Had Issues GETing to the backend, endpoint: stay/, with data: [object Object]
http.service.js:35 Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (https://hosty.onrender.com/static/js/main.bbd07398.js:2:70266)
    at y.onerror (https://hosty.onrender.com/static/js/main.bbd07398.js:2:65137)
stay.service.js:28 Cannot get stay Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (createError.js:16:15)
    at y.onerror (xhr.js:117:14)
```

My code in the frontend is

```
import Axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '//hosty-backend.onrender.com' : '//localhost:3030/api/';

//http service
var axios = Axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
});
export const httpService = {
  get(endpoint, data) {
    return ajax(endpoint, 'GET', data);
  },
  post(endpoint, data) {
    return ajax(endpoint, 'POST', data);
  },
  put(endpoint, data) {
    return ajax(endpoint, 'PUT', data);
  },
  delete(endpoint, data) {
    return ajax(endpoint, 'DELETE', data);
  },
};

async function ajax(endpoint, method = 'GET', data = null) {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      url: `${BASE_URL}${endpoint}`,
      method,
      data,
      params: method === 'GET' ? data : null,
    });
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Had Issues ${method}ing to the backend, endpoint: ${endpoint}, with data: ${data}`);
    console.dir(err);
    if (err.response && err.response.status === 401) {
      sessionStorage.clear();
      window.location.assign('/');
    }
    throw err;
  }
}
```

It's very important to say that my code works properly LOCALLY.
I have also tried to use

`const BASE_URL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://hosty-backend.onrender.com' : '//localhost:3030/api/';`

but still it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://render.com/docs/configure-environment-variables

Comment: thing is i have uploaded a different project who uses the same httpService and i had no issues or set any enviorment variables.